# Angular2 - route with language

Tags: angular

Hello i would like to create routes with language in this format:

```
www.domain.com/lang/sometimes
```

Example:

```
www.domain.com/en/sometimes
www.domain.com/de/sometimes
```

Is it possible write to route something like:

```
RouterModule.forChild({
   path: ':lang/sometimes', component: TestComponent
})
```

Is it possible? How to set to url default language? For example when app starting, set dynamically lang parameter to url.

Thank you for your advices

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like this then. You can create two routes, one for default route and another for other Routes.

```
 RouterModule.forChild([
  { path: 'english/users/sometimes', component: UserComponent, useAsDefault: true },
  { path: ':lang/users/sometimes', component: UserCOmponent }
])
```

Added: 
For subscribing to the param:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructior(private route: ActivatedRoute)

ngOnInit(){
this.route.params.subscribe(value => {
    let lang = value['lang']);
    console.log(lang);    

});
}
```

Comment: Thanks and how i get (or set) :lang parameter from url?

Comment: For accessing the routes from other components, you can do like this:                  `this.lang = someLanguage;                                        
 this.router.navigate([this.lang,'users','sometimes']);`

Comment: If you need to get the 'lang' parameter from the url. You can subscribe the params on ngOnInit of any component to where you want it.                     `this.route.params.subscribe(value => { let lang = value['lang'); });`

Comment: This not working: `this.route.params.subscribe(value => { let lang = value['lang'); });`. In url is /en/sometimes and params are empty. `this.route` is type of `ActivatedRoute`?

Comment: Can you view my updated comment? Yes, route is of type ActivatedRoute

Comment: I am sorry. It works. code for get param is running in component. But it is possible that change language in "background"?  Outside in component? It is any method which is called always? For example in Module. I dont want change language in each components.