# When changing language the route is appending to instead of just changing with chosen language

Tags: angular, angular-universal, ngx-translate, ngx-translate-multi-http-loader

When I am changing the language the route gets appended to previous routes instead of just changing the language for exe- `http://localhost:4200/en/about-us` if change the language to he then it becomes `http://localhost:4200/he/about-us/about-us`
I am changing the language like this.

```
constructor(
    public translate: TranslateService,
    private localize: LocalizeRouterService
){}
chooseLanguage('he') { 
        this.translate.use(lng);
        this.localize.changeLanguage(lng)
}
```

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
this.localize.changeLanguage(lng) here what you doing that might be affecting changing the route
```

if you using ngx-translate you can change the language just by using the below method

if you want to change the route as well checkout out this solution
[Angular2 - route with language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45096053/angular2-route-with-language)

```
constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.setDefaultLang('en'); // default language (in app.component)
  }
  
  useLanguage(language: string) {
    this.translate.use(language);
  }
```

Comment: I need to also changes route from previous language to the chosen one

Comment: why do you want to change the route

Comment: if you want to change route as well follow the below one while you navigating 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45096053/angular2-route-with-language

Comment: I am using https://github.com/gilsdav/ngx-translate-route for route management

Comment: have you followed this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-translate-routes-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

here we setting up this config in app.module so it will take all over the application once above one stackblitz working fine in your code then you can use the above angular route language change example

Comment: this example is translating the route but in my case I am putting a prefix in the route /en or /he

Comment: ngx-translate-route  we  using for that purpose only if you want to prefix go through this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45096053/angular2-route-with-language